# Find the longest decreasing sequence

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sequence

I am trying to find the longest sequence of decreasing numbers in an array. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly in the following code.

```
public static int getDecSeq(double[] data) {
  int currentSeq = 1;
  int currentIndex = 1;

  int longestSeq = 0;
  int longestIndex = 0;
  for (int i = currentIndex; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] < data[i - 1]) {
      currentSeq++;
    } else {
      currentSeq = 1;
      currentIndex = i;
    }
    if (currentSeq > longestSeq) {
      longestSeq = currentSeq;
      longestIndex = currentIndex;
    }
    //double[] sequence = new double[longestSeq];
    //for (int j = longestIndex; j < longestSeq; j++) {
      //sequence[j]
    //}
  }
  return longestSeq;
}//close getDecSeq
```

Looks like now the real problem is how to set up data correctly so that I can use it in the method.

getData(input) returns a bunch of numbers from a file and stores them in an array.

I wrote:

```
double[] data = getData(input);
System.out.println("longest sequence is" + getDecSeq(data));
```

I am doing this incorrectly. My methods work. When I declared the variable data as:

```
double[] data = {119.1, 186.4, 46.3, 89.0 ...};
```

Everything worked just fine. 
So how do rewrite the way I call data to work?

getData is

```
public static double[] getData(Scanner input) {
   double[] list = new double[70]; //Construct an array, length 70, to hold values from file
   int count = 0;
   while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
      double n = input.nextDouble();
      list[count] = n;
      count++;
   }
   double[] newList = new double[count];
   for (int i = 0; i < newList.length; i++ ) {
      newList[i] = list[i];

   }
   return newList;
}//close getData
```

Comment: What's your problem ? Please give an example for which your algorithm does not work...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878105/finding-the-longest-down-sequence-in-a-java-array  (but don't copy!)

Comment: Whats's your `getData` ? Please post the code of this function.

Comment: Inspect the result of getData (try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getData(input)));`)  Do the array contents match what you expect to see?  Maybe you're misunderstanding the file format (e.g., does maybe the first line in the file say how *many* doubles follow?)

Comment: That's exactly what I use to look at the result of getData, so it is the same.

Comment: @Robert so you're saying the exact same data yields different results if it's loaded from a file vs inputted manually?  I highly doubt that.  I think you're misreporting something; try to fill in the gaps in the information you're giving us.  Also compare the two arrays for equality by using `Arrays.equals(data, getData(input))`.

Comment: They are not equal. If I uses Arrays.toString it prints the same result and they appear to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks strikingly like my pseudocode posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878105/finding-the-longest-down-sequence-in-a-java-array/3878132#3878132).  One edge case you haven't covered is what to return if the loop is never run.  I would treat these as special cases.

e.g.

```
 if ( data.length < 2 ) return data.length;
```

Answer (score 3):

Is  `4444444` considered to be decreasing? If not then you want to check for strictly `<` rather than `<=`.

Could you provide a bit more, such as where your answer fails?

Comment: I think that may be what Robert might be looking for.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I forgot to get rid of the = but that still does not make it work.

Comment: @Robert Please please give an example !!

Comment: Turns out the method was correct and the data (the actual array) was declared incorrectly.

Comment: @Robert : good ! Look at answers from johnbk (shorter code) and user434507 (bug corrected) below. And please choose one of the answers .

Answer (score 2):

I see lot of redundant logic..i think this would do..

```
public static int getDecSeq(int[] data) {
        int currentSeq = 1, longestSeq = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            currentSeq = (data[i] < data[i - 1]) ? currentSeq + 1 : 1;
            if (currentSeq > longestSeq)
                longestSeq = currentSeq;
        }
        return longestSeq;
    }
```

I considered @Reese Moore's suggestion.

Comment: Attention, if the sequence has only one element you'll return 0 but we want 1. longestSeq must start at 1

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the code will correctly calculate the length of the longest sequence, there's only one bug that makes it incorrectly calculate the starting position of that sequence in some cases. Change it to this:

```
int currentSeq = 1;
int currentIndex = 0;

int longestSeq = 0;
int longestIndex = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
...
```

Comment: Might be the problem indeed but because the output is `longestSeq` the code should work anyway...

Comment: If current index starts at 0, there will be an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` thrown on the first check. Notice the `data[i - 1]`

Comment: Oh, I see, but then the definition of where currentIndex starts is irrelevant. You don't even need to keep track of it. You could just calculate the longest index by taking the end of the new longest sequence and subtracting the end of it.

Comment: @Reese: never mind the fact that it's not even relevant to know given what he's returning.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at when you assign longestSeq and longestIndex. It will help if you sketch out on paper first what you intend the algorithm to do for a given test input, and then run the algorithm while watching (printing) the Seq and Index values on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a little bit simpler.
You don't actually need to keep the index if you don't need it.

```
public int getDecSeq(double[] data)
{

    int curSequence = 1;
    int maxSequence = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= data.Length - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i] > data[i - 1]) {
            if (curSequence > maxSequence) {
                maxSequence = curSequence;
            }

            curSequence = 1;
        } else {
            curSequence += 1;
        }
    }

    if (curSequence > maxSequence) {
        maxSequence = curSequence;
    }

    return maxSequence;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like now the real problem is how to set up data correctly so that I can use it in the method.

I hadn't declared the array correctly in order to use it in the method. But the method works just fine.